# "_CMTimeGetSeconds",symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 -IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

By using this Code

```
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:selectedVideoUrl];
CMTime duration = playerItem.duration;
float seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(duration);
NSLog(@"duration: %.2f", seconds);
```

Error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_CMTimeGetSeconds", referenced from:
      -[VideoUpload imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:] in VideoUpload.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you linked the CoreMedia framework?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

CMTime is defined in the CoreMedia.framework. Add that framework to your project.

And take a look at Apple's [CMTime reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html)